# Automatically know the screen resolution apple devices

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to me a function that automatically returns the screen resolution on the device that I'm using (4S iPhone 3G 3GS 4, iPad, iPod, etc.), I wanted to avoid using the function that returns the type of device I and the second model go hand I set the resolution, I was wondering if you could have a function that will return the maximum screen resolution.

thanks

Comment: why do you want the screen resolution? It's not the recommended way to do thing. I'm assuming by resolution you mean pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` give what you want?

Comment: yeah, but if an iPad is running an iPhone only app, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] will return the simulated screen, thus 320x480